# Spring WebFlow: Getting HTTPServletRequest from ServletExternalContext

Tags: spring-webflow

Two related questions:

1. Old posts I have read state that ServletExternalContext has a method getRequest which returns the httpServletRequest. In the current version of Spring Webflow (2.4) this method is not visible (i.e., protected). So, can someone confirm that if I want to get httpServletRequest data (such as request URL) I have to do it through Spring MVC instead?
2. Second question: I understand that webflow is designed to work with multiple frameworks, not just servlets. However, I don't understand why it has to be completely brickwalled from the framework within which it is embedded. Can someone explain the reasoning

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, it is possible

   ```
   ServletExternalContext externalContext = (ServletExternalContext) ctx.getExternalContext();
   HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest)externalContext.getNativeRequest();
   ```
2. is moot